# Getting just the number of a String C#

Tags: c#

I have a string like this:

```
String mainString = "11;22;33;44;55;66";
```

and I want to get just the numbers and put them in Array or List.

what I did so far is get the `;` positions:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String mainString = "11;22;33;44;55;66";
        int count = mainString.Split(';').Length - 1;
        int firstComma = mainString.IndexOf(';');
        int index = mainString.IndexOf(';'); ;

        System.Console.WriteLine(firstComma);
        for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
        {
            index = mainString.IndexOf(';', index + 1);
            System.Console.WriteLine(index);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: You are already using `string.Split(';')`.  Why not use the array that produces?

Comment: I don't know how match number the user will enter, maybe "11;22;33", mayber just one "11".

Comment: as a sidenote, it's a semicolon, not a comma

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are already using string.Split. Just convert the strings to ints.

```
String mainString = "11;22;33;44;55;66";
int[] ints = mainString.Split(';').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Which part is hard for you :)

Comment: For me, none. For a person who is just beginning c#, probably everything after the Split part (do notice the OP does not even understand how Split works...)

Answer (score 2):

Don't understand why you're making this so complicated.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string mainString = "11;22;33;44;55;66";
    string[] array = mainString.Split(";");

    foreach (var s in array)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(s);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```